# React: Pass image from this.state in parent component to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, components, react-props

I have an image I've imported to a React class component like this:

`import Hat3 from './assets/hat3/hat3.png';`

To display this image in this component I can do:

`<img src={hat3} />`

I have a child component called FeaturedItem that looks like this:

`<FeaturedItem hat={this.state.hat3}/>`

I want to pass the `hat3` image to the FeaturedItem component via the prop `hat`. How can I store the `hat3` image in state so that I can pass it to the functional FeaturedItem component?

I've tried the following:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           // Doesn't work
           hat3: {hat3}
           // Doesn't work
           hat3: ${hat3}
           // Doesn't work
           hat3: `${hat3}`
        };
    }
```

What is the proper way to store this image in state so that I can pass it to the child component via props and display it in the child component?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
this.state = {
    hat3: Hat3
};
```

In case if this doesn't work, can you please share what error you are getting.

Comment: Wow. That was a pretty dumb mistake on my part. That worked, thanks for the help.